# Dynamically create buttons in c# by user at runtime

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How to create buttons dynamically after user input in C# (Visual Studio).
There is a text-box to enter how many buttons user wants?
Then my target is to create buttons below the input field as the user wants
then how can I get id's of that buttons?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        this.Controls.Add(buttons[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: @HarithaGayashan - Please don't put your code in the comments. Edit your question instead.

Comment: @HarithaGayashan - And what's wrong with your code? Does it compile?
 What happens when you run your code? Does it cause an error?

Comment: You should read [ask].

Answer (score 2):

Here I first added an event handler to the `textbox`, which is called whenever the text value is changed. The value is converted to the `int` value and then is used in a for loop statement. You can set your button's potion to the desired value using location property. Using tag or name property you can assign a unique value to your buttons. I hope the code helps.

Look at the code below :

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 textBox1.TextChanged += textBox1_TextChanged;
}

void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 var txtBox = sender as TextBox;
 if (txtBox == null) return;
 var count = Convert.ToInt16(txtBox.Text);
 //
 var xPosition = 0;
 for (var i = 1; i <= count; i++)
 {
  var button = new Button
  {
   Tag = string.Format("Btn{0}", i),
   Text = string.Format("Button{0}",i),                        
   Location = new Point(xPosition, 0)
  };
 xPosition = xPosition + 100;
 Controls.Add(button);
}
```

Comment: Add to your answer that if User for example change the text in that textbox twice there will be created Buttons with the same `Tag` and `Text`

Comment: Thanks  for your advice. But as a new member I think the answers that we share with the people are considered as simple samples which help them to find the best idea. I think we are not going to consider or solve all possible challenges that they may confront with. Don't you think so? Please let me know. Thank you.@S.Petrosov

Comment: Yes, of course, but to warn of a possible problem is never superfluous :)

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating Control(in your case Buttons) you can give them `Name` property. It will be very good if that name will be unique.

```
var btn = new Button();
btn.Name = "MyBtn";
btn.Text = "Our Button";
this.Controls.Add(btn);
```

For creation of N `buttons` you just need to put this in a Loop with N iterations and set `btn.Name` to something like "Name"+SomeNumber.
To set the Position of the Buttons to below the input you should set `btn.Left` and `btn.Top` to the corresponding coordinates.

Then when you need to work with generated Control/Button you can do search by that `Name` in the following way:

```
var btn = (Button)this.Controls.Find("MyBtn", true).First();
```

and do whatever you want with that Control/Button.

But in this case there is some danger as I am not checking if there was found any control with that name. If you write incorrect Name this will throw exception on `.First()`.

Comment: Please explain how this answers the question? I can see that this relates to creating buttons, but the OP doesn't appear to be having a problem with naming of the buttons.

Comment: @Enigmativity as we see from his added code he can create Buttons, he does not how to work with them after that. `how can I get id's of that buttons?` Buttons have not ID, they have Name for such kind of things and I have explained how to work with Names

Comment: No, the OP doesn't know how to create buttons. His code doesn't create buttons.

Comment: @Enigmativity my answer is providing part of dynamically creation of Button too

Comment: But the OP hasn't asked about that.

Comment: @Enigmativity OP's question -> `Then my target is to create buttons below the input field as the user wants then how can I get id's of that buttons?` , Your comment -> `No, the OP doesn't know how to create buttons. His code doesn't create buttons.`

Comment: @Enigmativity may be because he does not know how to do it correctly and asking about it?

Comment: So explain that. Explain what is wrong with the OP's code and what do do about it.